# Can't boot the liveUSB properly on ASUS x553m

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, asus

I've tested the boot media in another computer and it's fine there- boots straight to the live "Try before you install" desktop with no problems whatsoever.
However, I'm having difficuties getting it to work on my Asus x553m laptop to set up dual boot wth win10.
It will load the grub menu, but all of the options just result in a black screen with a cursor in the top left, sometimes static, sometimes blinking. It does not move on from this screen.
I've tried using *nomodset* as suggested in varous places, which causes some text output, but this stops as a line complaining about ASPM, where it hangs again.
Anyone got any ideas? (secure and fast boot are disabled, as well as win10 fast startup)

Comment: What did you use to burn the live usb. Try with rufus and choose eufi boot. Otherwise turn uefi off in bios.

Comment: I used rufus with BIOS or UEFI. Using CSM to boot the UEFI and Legacy versions still results in the same screen at one point or another in the installation, and win10 is installed in UEFI mode

Comment: In bios turn off uefi boot. Or burn with GPT option.

Comment: What ubuntu are you using btw?

Comment: 18.04.2 LTS 64-bit

Comment: Try burning with the gpt option with rufus, and go from there. Also set it back to uefi boot.

Comment: Have done, same behaviour. Hangs on a black screen, and gets up to ASPM with nomodset over quiet splash.